# Is there any way to restore the distribution name?

Tags: etc

I installed Ubuntu on my desktop years ago, and decided to add the BunsenLabs repository and install Bunsen desktop there. However there is one little thing: the package also replace the `/etc/os-release`. My question is how do I restore my `os-release` and also the `lsb-release`(which was also modified) back to it's original?

Original OS info:
Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit Xenial Xerus

New OS info:
BunsenLabs GNU/Linux 8.6 (Hydrogen)

My current `os-release`

```
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/BunsenLabs"
HOME_URL="https://bunsenlabs.org"
ID=bunsenlabs
ID_LIKE="debian"
NAME="BunsenLabs GNU/Linux"
PRETTY_NAME="BunsenLabs GNU/Linux 8.6 (Hydrogen)"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.bunsenlabs.org"
VERSION="8.6 (Hydrogen)"
VERSION_ID="8.6"
```

My current `lsb-release`

```
DISTRIB_ID="BunsenLabs"
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="BunsenLabs GNU/Linux 8.6 (Hydrogen)"
DISTRIB_RELEASE="8.6"
DISTRIB_CODENAME="bunsen-hydrogen"
```

Output of `apt-cache policy base-files`

```
base-files:
  Installed: 9.4ubuntu4.3
  Candidate: 9.4ubuntu4.3
  Version table:
 *** 9.4ubuntu4.3 500
        500 http://opensource.xtdv.net/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     9.4ubuntu4 500
        500 http://opensource.xtdv.net/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy base-files` report?

Comment: @muru edited the post to add input

Comment: Also here's the `bunsen-*` repository: https://www.bunsenlabs.org/repositories.html

Comment: Given that `/etc/os-release` comes from `base-files`, and your `base-files` seems to be from Ubuntu, try http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27763/70524

Comment: @Zanna Dunno, I tested it with `/etc/os-release` and it worked fine - you did remember to actually delete the file?

Comment: @muru haha my bad as always!

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer.

According to a site an user linked to me, the command `dpkg -S os-release` showed:

```
diversion by bunsen-os-release from: /etc/os-release
diversion by bunsen-os-release to: /etc/os-release.bunsen-orig
```

Inside the `os-release.bunsen-orig` is the original `os-release` file. I also noticed that the `os-release` is just a simlink to `os-release.bunsen` and the `os-release.bunsen-orig` is the simlink to the "very" original `os-release` file which was in `/usr/lib/os-release`. Since I am too lazy to figure out how to make simlinks I simply *copied the `os-release.bunsen-orig` to `os-release`*.